# Можно ли вызвать НЕ synchronized метод "заблокированного" объекта?

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть 2 потока, один из них начал выполнение synchronized метода, внутри которого применяется Thread.sleep(5000). **Может ли другой поток использовать другие НЕСИНХРОНИЗИРОВАННЫЕ методы этого "заблокированного" объекта?**
Как я понимаю, "блокируется" не сам объект, а лишь synchronized участи кода (либо методы).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно совершать данное действие. Почему бы просто не попробовать? Вы правильно понимаете.

Comment: Да, так и есть, спасибо